# A weird differentiation question.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was looking at questions on differentiation and came across a weird form that both me and my friend had two different approaches to. This was the question.

Calculate the derivative:

$$ \frac{d(x-\sin(x))}{d(1-\cos(x))} $$

My approach was to factorize out an $x$ in the denominator of the fraction and differentiate as normal like so:

$$ \frac{d(x-\sin(x))}{dx(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\cos(x)}{x})} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x-\sin(x)}{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{\cos(x)}{x}}) $$

My friend's approach was to let $ u = 1-\cos(x) $ and to then take the approach that way leading to an answer.

Which way would be considered correct and why would this work? Thank you!

Comment: is this the function $$f(x)=\frac{x-\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$$?

Comment: $dx$ does not mean $d \cdot x$, so the first approach doesn't make sense.

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, this was only give to us. Assume that instead of $dy$ we get $ d(x - sin(x)) $ and instead of $dx$ we get $d(1-cos(x))$

Comment: By the way, I would say that a good first step for this question is to clarify what the question even means, because the notation being used in the question is not standard. One guess is that you are being asked to evaluate $\frac{df}{dx}/\frac{dg}{dx}$, where $f(x) = x - \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = 1 - \cos(x)$.

Comment: $sin(x)=\sqrt{1-(u-1)^2}$

Comment: For me the ony "way" to give a meaning to your expression is to write it under the form : $\frac{d(x-sin(x))}{dx}.\frac{dx}{d(1-cos(x))}$ i.e., the quotent of two classical differentiations : $\frac{d(x-sin(x))}{dx}/\frac{d(1-cos(x))}{dx}$

Comment: Changed what the question was trying to ask. Perhaps calculation of a derivative is a better way of saying what this is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dz} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{dz}{dx}}$$

Let $y = x-\sin(x)$ and $z=1-\cos(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Use the "chain rule", $\frac{df}{dx}= \frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$ with $f(x)= x- \sin(x)$  and $y= 1- \cos(x)$.  So we have $\frac{df}{dx}= 1- \cos(x)$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}= \sin(x)$.  Putting those into the "chain rule", $1- \cos(x)= \left(\frac{df}{dy}\right)(\sin(x))$ so $\frac{d(x- \sin(x))}{d(1- \cos(x)}= \frac{df}{dy}= \frac{1- \cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$.  You can, if you prefer, write that as $\frac{d(x- \sin(x))}{d(1- \cos(x))}= \frac{1}{\sin(x)}- \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}= \csc(x)- \cot(x)$.

Comment: Please format trig function with an immediately preceding "\":  `\cos x` to get $\cos x$, instead of $cos x$.